# Passing a wire handler or variable array to a function?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

I created a function in a separated JavaScript file called: "MapMarkers.js", and wanted to know if its possible to pass the wire handler or variable array that stores the data via querying directly from Apex, to the "MapMarkers" function. The Wire Service works correctly when displaying the data in HTML, but I want to be able to record and store my data to an array in the JavaScript file.

***The main goal is to display this data via a map-marker in the lighting-maps. Is it possible to do? Or should I do a different method to accomplish my goal? (like importing the array to the JS?)***

****The LWC Code:****

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';

// Importing from the "MapMarkers.js" file.
import { MapMarkers } from './MapMarkers';

// Importing from the "mappingBox" LWC.
import { SearchString, SearchState } from 'c/mappingBox';

// Importing from the "messageChannels" folder.
import { subscribe, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import COUNTER_FILE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/updatecounter__c';

// Importing Apex "QueryData" code, to get Opportunity object and fields data.
import getOpportunityList from '@salesforce/apex/QueryData.getOpportunityList';

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Global Variables.
let SearchStreet = '20 abc St';
let SearchCity = 'boston';

export default class Mapping extends LightningElement {

    // ** Still in work **

    myArray
    @wire(getOpportunityList) 
    WiredOpportunities({data, error}){
        if(data){
            this.myArray = data
        }

        if(error){
            console.error(error)
        }
    }

//Would It be possible to pass "myArray", to my function, then break it up in the "MapMarkers.js" file? 
//Or should I import "myArray" to my file?
mapMarkers = MapMarkers(SearchCity, SearchState, SearchStreet, myArray);
```

**MapMarkers.js**

```
// Could Importing from the "mapping.js" file work?
// import { opportunities } from './mapping';

// This function is for inputting all the "Opportunities", and the search location to the map.
export function MapMarkers(SearchCity, SearchState, SearchStreet, myArray){
```

**Apex Code:**

```
public with sharing class QueryData {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Opportunity> getOpportunityList() {
    
        List<Opportunity> OppList = new List<Opportunity>();
        OppList = [SELECT Id, Service_Address__c, Development_Rep__c, Name, Project_Type__c, CloseDate FROM Opportunity LIMIT 5];
    
        return OppList;
    
    }
  
}
```

***Lastly:***

I would like to apologize for asking a lot of questions or any similar questions, for the past two weeks. I'm fairly new with Salesforce development/programming, as I'm also trying to accomplish a complete a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `mapMarkers` is meant to be bound like this: `<lightning-map map-markers={mapMarkers}></lightning-map>`, then you just need to do that in your wire handler:

```
mapMarkers;
@wire(getOpportunityList) handleGetOpportunityList({data}) {
  if(data) {
    this.mapMarkers = MapMarkers(SearchCity, SearchState, SearchStreet, data);
  }
}
```

Or, if you mean to have the search variables eventually being updated based on user input, you can do that, too. Here's an example of that:

```
@wire(getOpportunityList) opportunities;
mapMarkers;
handleInputChange(event) {
  // update whichever search variable, then...

  this.mapMarkers = MapMarkers(SearchCity, SearchState, SearchStreet, this.opportunities.data);
}
```

Note: Be warned that your global variables really are global in respect to your component. If you add the component more than once, a change will affect all components, which may cause undesirable behavior if you're not careful. Unless/until you feel comfortable with that possibility, I'd strongly recommend you only use class variables.

Comment: So, I am calling the function twice, once before the search button is clicked and then again when the search button is clicked it reruns within that method. Would the be a problem? Should I include the wire handler twice?

Comment: After I pass the `data` to the `mapmakers` function I wanted to see what the data looked like, so I added to the mapmakers "description:", and my output is "[object Object],[object Object],". Is my data not loading?

Comment: @Pinto `[object Object]` is what happens when you try to turn an object into a String with the default Object.toString function. In other words, `console.log('my data:' + this.mapMarkers)` will output `my data: [object Object]`, but if you write `console.log('my data', this.mapMarkers)`, you'll see the contents of your object.

Comment: What happens when it outputs nothing when doing that? because nothing is output when I change to a ","

Comment: **Update:** I was able to figure it out, maybe it's because I was using the alert() function. But `alert(JSON.stringify(this.mapMarkers));` Worked for me, as I was able to view my data.

Comment: @Pinto console.log writes to the console. Press F12 on your keyboard to view it. And yes, alert will convert anything to a string, which was why you saw `[object Object]`

Comment: Thank you, that helped!